# C# WPF datgird IvalueConverter binding problems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, ivalueconverter

I have a datagrid, and the itemssoure is a ObservableCollection.
And I want to change it's values format before it goes to the datagrid.
Below is the code of xaml.

```
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding Path=Cash, Converter={StaticResource DecimalConverter}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>                                
                        </Style.Setters>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

The column I want to change is "Cash", and the IValueConverter is here.

```
public class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double result = 0;
        if (value is double)
            result = (double)value;
        return result.ToString("F2");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When I put the break the break point on the function DecimalConverter, it is actually begining called, and processing as the way I want(return The format as F2).
But It is not working, the datagrid still showing the value in a unprocessed way.
I know I have other ways to achieve this, but I just want to know why this is not working. It is the IValueConverter or the xaml code is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataGridCell` has no `TextBlock.Text` property so your `Style` has no effect at all.

I guess you are using auto-generated columns. You could then handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and set the `StringFormat` property of the binding:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridTextColumn col = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
    if (col != null && e.PropertyType == typeof(double))
    {
        col.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "F2" };
    }
}
```

Comment: It works well on my case, but I am wondering if the value is keep changing by calling NotifyPropertyChanged. Will it cost a lot on the system?
Anyway, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting a WPF DataGrid is notoriously difficult. There are hundred of things that can go wrong. In your case, it doesn't make sense that you want to assign a Converter for the "Cash" column to EVERY Cell in the grid.

Use DataGrid.CellStyle if you want to do something for all cells.

Use  DataGridColumn.CellStyle if you want to do something for all cells in a column.

Your next problem is the binding. In a DataGrid, each row has to bind to a different Record. WPF made expressly for this purpose the DataGridColumn.Binding property. It creates during runtime for each data record a new binding to a new row in the DataGrid.

I guess you will encounter also other problems and it is not really meaningful to spend so much time on finding out why it is not working. It is better if you do it just the right way. You can find a detailed description on how to do databinding and formatting correctly for a WPF DataGrid in my article [CodeProject.com: Guide to WPF DataGrid formatting using bindings](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings)

Answer (score 0):

DataGridCell style is not the correct place to set the text binding. Use the binding of the data grid column instead:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Cash, Converter={StaticResource DecimalConverter}}" />
```

Comment: My datagrid'itemssource is already equal to a ObservableCollection, if I use the way you suggest, It will give me the exception: Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.